# index.html not working when moved outside the folder

Tags: tailwind-css

I am fairly new to tailwindcss. I got their installation stuff **working** but I want to make changes in the dir files. I want my `index.html` outside from the `src` folder, but everytime I move it outiside `src` the tailwind class does not work.

here's my [directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaDGC.png)

`package.json`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.12"
  }
}
```

`tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold text-purple-700">
    안녕하세요
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the `content` field in the **tailwind.config.js** file. In your current project settings, html and js source files should be in directory **{project_directory}/src/**. In your current settings, the project directory structure should be as follows:

```
project_directory/
   |
   |--- tailwind.config.js
   |
   |--- dist/
   |       | 
   |       |--- output.css 
   |
   |--- src/ 
           |
           |--- input.css
           |
           |--- index.html
           |
           |--- main.js
```

You can move source files to different directories by updating field `content` in file **tailwind.config.js**. In the example below, the definition in the `content` field in the **tailwind.config.js** file is to show that the **index.html** file can be located in the project root directory. For more information, read the document in the references section.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{html,js}',
    './pages/**/*.{html,js}',
    './index.html',
  ]
}
```

If you want to move the **index.html** file to the project root, update the `content` field in the **tailwind.config.js** file as follows:

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{html,js}',
    './index.html'
  ]
}
```

---

###### References

- [Configuring Source Path - Pattern Recommendations](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#pattern-recommendations)

Answer (score 0):

using the chrome inspector tool console, check if the css file is loaded. If it shows 404 error, your css file link is wrong.